# Group Ring and Augmentation Ideal of Baumslag Solitar Groups

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $m,n$ be integers. The Baumslag Solitar Group if defined by

$$G=G_{m,n}=\langle a,b: ba^{m}b^{-1}=a^{n}\rangle $$

This group acts naturally on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by multiplication and I want to compute the Cohomology groups $H^{k}(G_{1,2},\mathbb{R}^{2})$ for $k=0,1,2,...$

My Approach:

The matrices $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ make a copy of $G=G_{1,2}$. By definition

$$H^{0}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:g\cdot x=x, \ \text{for all} \ g\in G\}$$

It is easy to see by a simple calculation that $H^{0}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})=0$. On the other hand $H^{1}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is defined by

$$H^{1}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})=\frac{\operatorname{Der}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})}{ \operatorname{Ider}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})}$$

And.... again... by a simple calculation $H^{1}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})=0$

In order to compute $H^{2}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})$ I want to use the identity

$$H^{2}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})=H^{1}(G, \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(I[G], \mathbb{R}^{2}))$$

My quetions are:

1.- If $G=\langle A,B\rangle $ how to compute the group ring  $\mathbb{Z}[G]$?

2.- If $G=\langle A,B\rangle $ how to compute the augmentation ideal  $I[G]$?

3.- Is there an easy way to compute $H^{2}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})$?

4.- How to compute $H^{k}(G,\mathbb{R}^{2})$ for $k>2$?

Comment: $H^k(G,M)=0$ for all $k>2$ and all $ZG$-modules $M$. As for $H^2$, you should use either MV-sequence (since $BS(2,1)$ is an HNN-extension of $Z$ by $Z$) or the LSH-spectral sequence associated with the decomposition of $B(2,1)$ as a semidirect product of $Z$ and the group of diadic rationals.  Both are covered in Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups."

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Moishe Kohan. But why is $H^{2}(G,M)=0$ for $k>2$ and all $\mathbb{Z}[G]-$module?

Comment: This is because all BS-groups have cohomological dimension 2: Their standard presentation complexes are aspherical with universal cover homeomorphic to tree times line.

Comment: Thank you again. My motivation is found a soluble not nilpotent $G$ acting linearly on a finite dimensional vector space $M$ such that $H^{0}(G,M)=0$ but $H^{k}(G,M)\neq 0$ for some k.

Comment: Then you can even take $BS(1,-1)$, the fundamental group of the Klein bottle, acting on ${\mathbb R}$ nontrivially (via its orientation character). Both $H^1$ and $H^2$ will be nontrivial, while $H^0$ will be zero.

Comment: By the way: where can I found a proof that all BS(m,n) have cohomological dimension 2?

Comment: @MoisheKohan if $g\in G=BS(1,-1)$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, I'm sorry but I still can not see how to define $g\cdot x$ in order to obtain a  $G-$module structure over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $g$ is orientation-reversing, send it to $-1$, otherwise, to $+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, $H^2(G, {\mathbb R}^2)=0$. The simplest way to see this is to use Euler characteristic with coefficients in the ${\mathbb R}G$-module $M$. It is a general fact that
$$
\chi(G, M)= \dim_{\mathbb R}(M)\cdot \chi(G),
$$
where $\chi(G)=\chi(K(G,1))$. For all Baumslag-Solitar groups $G$, the natural presentation complex is $K(G,1)$, from which it follows that $\chi(K(G,1))=0$. Now, in your example, you already know that
$$
H^0(G,{\mathbb R}^2)=H^1(G,{\mathbb R}^2)=0. 
$$
Since $\chi(G, M)=0$ where $M={\mathbb R^2}$, it follows that  $H^2(G,{\mathbb R}^2)=0$ as well: Since presentation complex is a 2-dimensional $K(G,1)$, all BS groups have cohomological dimension 2, hence, for every ${\mathbb Z}G$-module $M$,
$$
H^i(G, M)=0, i\ge 3. 
$$
Thus, for your module $M$, you get:
$$
0=\chi(G, M)= \dim H^0(G,M) - \dim H^1(G, M) + \dim H^2(G, M)=H^2(G, M).  
$$

Comment: Again thank you so much. By the way, where did you learn all this tools? Can you give me some book references on Cohomology of Groups, Homological Álgebra and Algebraic Topology, and BS(m, n)  Groups?

Comment: @JoseCamarillo: Few of these things are discussed in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. I used Brown's "Cohomolgy of Groups" to learn the subject, especially the topological viewpoint of it. Otherwise, I learn it by doing it. I am not sure there is a textbook treatment of BS groups; google revealed https://www.google.com/books/edition/On_the_Baumslag_Solitar_Groups_and_Certa/eMAatwAACAAJ?hl=en

Comment: Also,  which is the definition of Euler característic,? Some book references Will ve apreciate

Comment: OK... Thank you so much for the time and your answers